# Installing Editor in AWS Workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-workspaces

I have AWS Workspace as the only interface given to us to work with AWS. However, I want to write scripts say Cloudformation - how do I install any editor ? Also, is it possible to use Terraform with AWS workspaces?

Is it possible to install VSCODE on AWS workspaces ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I learnt that it is possible to install vscode,terraform,python on your workspace. We just need a browser installed with open internet connection. Works !